# How to specify the current directory in Windows Shell?

Tags: shell, scripting, batch-file

I have the following BAT file which is intended to archive the specified folder, protect it by a password and copy the archive file to my local Dropbox folder.

```
    "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx9 archive.7z "G:\This is a test\directory\with subdirectories\" -psecret -mhe=on

    xcopy "G:\This is a test\directory\with subdirectories\archive.7z" "G:\My Documents\My Dropbox\" /c /d /s /e /k /y
```

I use 7-Zip for archiving.

Is it possible to alter the script in such a way that I can put it in any folder I choose and it does the same - archive the current folder, protect it by a password and copy the archive file to my local Dropbox folder?

Simply said, what is the command for "archive the current directory and any sub-directories"?

Answer (score 42):

`%CD%` is your current directory. Try `echo %CD%` in a dos prompt to try it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can specify "the current directory" simply as `.`, for example:

```
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -mx9 archive.7z . -psecret -mhe=on
xcopy archive.7z "G:\My Documents\My Dropbox\" /c /d /s /e /k /y
```

It's just a more complicated case of doing something as easy as `dir .`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current directory path if from the script path you put this line at the top of your script file:

```
$CurrentDirectory = Split-Path $MyInvocation.InvocationName
```